Why is Linux Libertine not matched in Firefox?
How does Firefox decide which font to render? It renders the Wikipedia headlines in Nimbus Roman, which is ugly, the CSS says 'Linux Libertine','Georgia','Times','Source Serif Pro',serif and I installed Linux Libertine and configured it so that it is matched by the system:
~> fc-match "Linux Libertine, Georgia, Times, Source Serif Pro, serif"
LinLibertine_R.otf: "Linux Libertine O" "Regular"

But Fixefox apparently wants the name to match exactly, Linux Libertine O works, although I put
<alias binding="same">
  <family>Linux Libertine</family>
  <accept><family>Linux Libertine O</family></accept>
</alias>

in /etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-linux-libertine.conf. Does Firefox only look at the OTF files and its embedded family names?
